# Javascript and module pattern

Tags: javascript

i think i did not understand javascript module pattern.

I just create this module:

```
var mycompany = {};
mycompany.mymodule = (function() {
    var my = {};
    var count = 0;

    my.init = function(value) {
        _setCount(value);
    }

    // private functions
    var _setCount = function(newValue) {
        count = newValue;
    }
    var _getCount = function() {
        return count;
    }

    my.incrementCount = function() {
        _setCount(_getCount() + 1);
    }
    my.degreeseCount = function() {
        _setCount(_getCount() - 1);
    }

    my.status = function() {
        return count;
    }

    return my;
})();


var a = mycompany.mymodule;
var b = mycompany.mymodule;
console.debug(a, 'A at beginning');
console.debug(a, 'B at beginning');
a.init(5);
b.init(2);
console.log('A: ' + a.status()); // return 2 (wtf!)
console.log('B: ' + b.status()); // return 2`
```

Where is the mistake? 
I thought that my code would have returned to me not 2 value, but 5.

What's the reason?

Comment: I think you have to use *var a = new mycompany.mymodule*. Else it just refrence to object.

Answer (score 2):

`a` and `b` are the exact same objects.

```
var a = mycompany.mymodule;
var b = mycompany.mymodule;
```

What you want to do is create two different objects which have the same prototype. Something similar to this:

```
mycompany.mymodule = (function () { 
  var my = function () {};
  my.prototype.init = function (value) {
    _setCount(value);
  };
  my.prototype.incrementCount = ...
  // ...

  return my;
}());

a = new mycompany.mymodule();
b = new mycompany.mymodule();
a.init(5);
b.init(2);
```

For more info, research "javascript prototypal inheritance"

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, objects are passed by reference, not copied.

To explain further, here is a simplified version of your code:

```
var pkg = (function () {
  var x = {};
  return x;
}());

var a = pkg;
var b = pkg;
```

You do not create two separate objects but only reference the object pointed at by `pkg` from both `a` and `b`. `a` and `b` are exactly the same.

```
a === b // true
```

This means that calling a method on `a` you are ultimately doing the same to `b` (it points to the same object—`x`.)

You don't want to use the module pattern for this. You want the usual constructor+prototype.

```
function Pkg() {
  this.count = 0;
};
Pkg.prototype.init = function (count) { this.count = count; };

var a = new Pkg();
var b = new Pkg();

a === b // false

a.init(2);
a.count === 2 // true
b.count === 2 // false
```

Comment: thanks! can i make count a private variable? and for others private functions?

Comment: Why? Private in JS means "don't touch that" which we signal by using an underscore in front or behind the variable name. If you insist, you can have `function Pkg() { this.count = 0; this.init = function () { ... }; }` The variable `count` is then only visible to the constructor and the method `init`.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) is a good read about module pattern.